# How to connect HP printer with PC via Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless, printing, hp, hplip

I am trying to setup my HP printer using Wi-Fi on PC, but when I try to do it using Wireless Method it connects it but only with specific IP adress that is in use at the moment of connecting. When I try Wirless and USB combined method result is the same. So how can I set it up withoute specific IP adress? Or I can maybe force my Wi-Fi router to only put a specific IP adress to printer?

NOTE: I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and newest version of HPLIP. Printer is HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 4535.

Comment: Depends on your router. In my case, I can set an IP address/MAC address combination to ensure the printer always connects as directed.

Comment: So how can I do it? It is probably quite similar.

Comment: You need to log into your router from a webpage (usually 192.168.1.1) enter your router manager name and password and you should find the relevant page from there under DHCP settings perhaps. Mine is a Huawei B528

Comment: You can also address the printer using CUPS by typing the URL http://localhost:631/

Comment: I assign static IP adress so now everything works fine.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then if you would be so kind as to accept it to make it easier for others with the same issue to find it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which router you have you should log into it and set an IP address/MAC address combination.

This will usually be a menu option in the DHCP settings.

Log in to your Router (usually) with the address 192.168.1.1 in your browser), enter the username and password for the router (often admin and admin respectively) and add the static IP address you require and MAC address association (MAC address often given on the status page of the printer) and save to exit the program.

That will then set your printer to always use that IP address on the WiFi network.